# Getting twitter shares count, response giving weird output

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

```
//this function is the callback, it needs to be a global variable
        window.readResponse = function (response){
            document.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')[0].innerHTML = response;
        }

        (function(){
            //note the "readResponse" at the end
            $URL = "http://www.google.com/"
            var src = 'http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' + $URL + '&callback=readResponse',
            script = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
            script.src = src;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        })();
```

That above is my codes to get the shares count. But when I do the request, the response I am getting is

```
function (){ //note the "readResponse" at the end $URL = "http://www.google.com/" var src = 'http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' + $URL + '&callback=readResponse', script = document.createElement('SCRIPT'); script.src = src; document.body.appendChild(script); }
```

Where as I am expecting the response.count is the actual share count.

I setup a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/zs1dgs45/5/

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Twitter have [stopped supporting the share count API](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/hard-decisions-for-a-sustainable-platform). Sorry.